# CSS How to change input font-size

Tags: css

The `font-size` of the `input` tag wont increase. I know it's following the browser/os set rules, but shouldn't it be able to be overridden?

```html
<style>
input[type="search"]
{
  font-size:50px;
}
</style>
<form class="search-box" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="search" name="q" placeholder=" welcome back" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
</form>
```

**Result**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpfiP.jpg

Comment: I copy pasted an it is working locally for me...

Comment: According to the console in your screenshot, it is rendering at 50px. I assume that the same goes if you were to select `.bookmarks`? What OS are you using? I'm thinking that this is because IOS doesn't allow styling on certain elements. What happens if you use a standard "text" instead of "search"?

Comment: @Harmonic It does work with 'text' just not search. MacOS

Comment: @Robby,
Ok then the issue is almost certainly because of MacOS. Please either just use a text input, or check out my below answer that might solve the issue for you if you wish to keep the search type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does apple stuff.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

```
input[type=search]{
   -moz-appearance: none;/* older firefox */
   -webkit-appearance: none; /* safari, chrome, edge and ie mobile */
   appearance: none; /* rest */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've just created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8on3hp4/) of your code, and it works as expected. I believe there is some other css rule overwriting your rule.

So you can try adding `!important` to your rule, eg:

```
input[type="search"]
{
  font-size:50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a class to the input like:

```css
<style type="text/css">
.search{
font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-box" action="https://www.google.com/search">
<input class="search" type="search" name="q" placeholder=" welcome back" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```